# overflow:hidden div is still scrollable on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i'm building an one-page website and the transition animation is a .PNG of a circle that expands and shrinks like those on Android, i had "overflow:hidden" in the "body" element but apparently mobile browsers don't take both "body" or "html" tags into consideration, so i created a wrapper div that sits on top of the flow containing only the circle, and again, works as intended on desktop but not on mobile, i'm sorry if i missed something but i've been browsing about this for the week without any results. the circle is inserted in the div with jquery when needed and deleted when the animation is over.

Comment: This will be hard to understand without looking at the project.

Comment: Really appreciate if you can share the URL! It may be due to the other div/container.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might not be the mobile browser, but the small width of the viewport. On you desktop, resize the browser window to make it small and see if the scrollbar shows up. If it does, then open the Developer tools and check what container actually has the scrollbar.

To see which html node has scroll, in Firefox there should be a `scroll` purple label next to the node. Check this screen:

[image]

It might be that another container has the scrollbar, so you need to set `overflow hidden` there too.